# Vertical alignment of two INPUT:RADIO groups in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot get two very simple groups of INPUT:RADIO to be vertically aligned:

[image: Alignment mismatch]

```
<!-- Group 1 -->
<div class='radio btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>

    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='grp1' />G1 Sel1
    </label>
    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='grp1' />G1 Sel2
    </label>
    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='grp1' />G1 Sel3
    </label>

</div>

<!-- Group 2 -->
<div class='radio btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>

    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='grp2' />G2 Sel1
    </label>
    <label class='btn btn-primary'>
        <input type='radio' name='grp2' />G2 Sel2
    </label>

</div>
```

I have tried to use the `btn-toolbar` class but as it is not buttons, this will not work. There is no `form` as I just need to detect the click within the two groups.

JSFiddle demo, http://jsfiddle.net/kcPDH/

How can I get the two groups to be vertically aligned?

Comment: Actually I just found out that if I remove the `radio` class on the two `div` it works perfectly - no margin/padding and vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Please add these code to your code:

```
.radio + .radio, .checkbox + .checkbox {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bobkhin/xJRD8/)

Comment: I can see it is working but I don't understand it. Why does it work? And what conserquences does it have on other places where I use radio buttons? There must be another, better, way of fixing this?

Comment: The reason is BS add `.radio + .radio, .checkbox + .checkbox` in CSS with property is `margin-top: -5`. That's why the second btn-group is not same vertical-align with first one.

Comment: Having different setup, e.g. having 3 radio-groups, would then need a new CSS style. I really don't like this approach and would rather build it with a table setup instead but ideally this could be solved more elegantly.

Comment: Why you dont like this approach? Maybe you can add a class such as `my-radio` and make `margin-top: 10px !important` (if you want)